# Getting "variable is undefined" or "variable.map" is not a function while trying to fetch data from JSON response

Tags: json, reactjs

I have done this before, but I am not sure what error I am making here in order to populate the select drop down with options retrieved from JSON response. The API call is successfull and I can see the data pulled but not able to display it in options of select drop down.

varibale in concern is idsFetched

```
            let idsFetched = this.state.storeRanges.Stores
            console.log("ranges I/O ", idsFetched);

            let options3 = idsFetched.map(store => {
                    return {value: store.value.description, label: store.value.description};
                })
```

```
---- JSON RESPONSE ---- Stored in variable = storeRanges

{
    "Stores": [
        {
            "mode": "LOADED",
            "value": {
                "description": "Ontario-Example-123",
            }
        },
        {
            "mode": "LOADED",
            "value": {
                "description": "Ontario-Example-456",
            }
        },
        {
            "mode": "LOADED",
            "value": {
                "description": "Ontario-Example-789",
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your code should work, can you please provide more info or can you copy paste the whole component ?

Comment: Is the JSON response you provided is from console.log(), Please provide output from console.log(). It seems like your API didn't returned the value yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by declaring an empty variable in state and then updating the state in ComponentDidUpdate hook and accessing that in onChange method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProp, prevState){
this.setState({idsFetched: this.state.storeRanges.Stores})
}

onChange(){
options = ranges.map(range => {
                    return {value: range.value.description, label: range.value.description};
                })
}
```

This is how I could access the array of stores fetched from JSON response!

Thank you everyone for looking into my query!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have done `JSON.parse(apiResponse)` otherwise you'll just be storing a string, making `storeRanges.Stores === undefined` probably causing your issue.

Secondly, make sure the State has been set first, by wrapping the function in a check. If you've done it correctly the re-render after setting state should fire it off no worries

Comment: Yeah I had stored the JSON API response but the issue was after I do that while retrieving list within the list of JSON response.